# MySQL - Do queries *always* begin searching at the start of the table?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find a clear answer for this anywhere in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/).

When I run a query, something like:

*Code Block 1*

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE status=1');
```

does the search start at the beginning of the table, at `row 0` (or the lowest available row)?

What I'm trying to do is go through a table one row at a time, and then exit when I get to the end:

*Code Block 2*

```
$curRow = 0;

while(true){
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE status=? AND id>? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array(0, $curRow));

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(count($result)){
        $curRow = $result[0]['id'];

        $stmt2 = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET status=? WHERE id=?');
        $stmt2->execute(array(1, $curRow));

        ... do some other stuff ...
    }else{
        exit();
    }
}
```

And so far, in testing, this has worked exactly as intended. But will it always be so?

**Possible erroneous case:**

Start out with the following table:

```
table

id | name | status
-- | ---- | ------
 1 |  ... |   0
 2 |  ... |   0
 3 |  ... |   0
 4 |  ... |   0
 5 |  ... |   0
 6 |  ... |   0
```

And run the query in *Code Block 2*. Say it starts at the first row, so now we have `$curRow=1`, and the table looks as follows:

```
table

id | name | status
-- | ---- | ------
 1 |  ... |   1
 2 |  ... |   0
 3 |  ... |   0
 4 |  ... |   0
 5 |  ... |   0
 6 |  ... |   0
```

All is well. The code does whatever it needs to, and then continues with the loop. *Any* of the remaining rows will satisfy the conditions in `$stmt` (i.e. `status=0` and `id>$curRow`).

Will the statement always look at consecutive rows when checking the conditions? If not, it could end up at any arbitrary row, say the third:

```
table

id | name | status
-- | ---- | ------
 1 |  ... |   1
 2 |  ... |   0
 3 |  ... |   1
 4 |  ... |   0
 5 |  ... |   0
 6 |  ... |   0
```

And now we have `$curRow=3`, which means the query will *never* go back and look at the second row.

I know it's tricky business speaking in absolutes (always, never, every time, ...), but is there a way to ensure that the query begins at the lowest available row? Or does MySQL handle this automatically?

Comment: A table represents a mere set of records regardless of any order. If you want to select data in a particular order use `ORDER BY`. Accordingly a `LIMIT` clause without an `ORDER BY` clause doesn't make much sense. You simply get one record of the table arbitrarily chosen.

Comment: don't depend on it. depending on the table type/engine being used, doing an update on the table you're selecting from can invalidate things for the select.

Comment: According to the ANSI SQL standard, there are no guarantees. Any current observed behavior on the order can change without notification between versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee for any reliable order when you do not explicitly set it to a key. It might seem to be ordered for now, but over time, with more data, maybe with more servers, partitioned data, union'ed data, it will change quickly to something unexpected.

Better use `ORDER BY`:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE status=1 ORDER BY ID ASC');
```

Make sure you have an index on the column you want to order by, it will speed up things!

Answer (score 1):

You should not write such a code which has such assumptions of your database. Your code might get less maintainable, harder to debug when some change comes to your database and that'll be a total headache for you. You should think of other mechanisms / workarounds to get the job done which is also more professional.

You might want to add a column which will provide that they can be ordered. For example date, ID, whatsoever.

Look up [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause.